# How to convert longitude and latitude into street address using android 6.0?

Tags: android

I am developing an app,In this I'm using google map in android 6.0 and below the versions 6.0 both to find current location of user.The problem is my app shows proper current location of user in map but not show street address of user in textfield and the devices of android os version less than 6.0 shows the current location of street address in textfield. Following is the which i used. Please Suggest me, How do i solve this using android marshmallow?

```
java

    public class Maps_Activity1 extends FragmentActivity implements
            OnMapReadyCallback,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
            View.OnClickListener {

        //Our Map
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        public static final int REQUEST_ID_ACCESS_COURSE_FINE_LOCATION = 100;
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 100;

        //To store longitude and latitude from map
        private double longitude;
        private double latitude;
        String caddress;

        //Buttons
        private ImageButton buttonSave;
        private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
        private ImageButton buttonView;

        private Button btnProceed, btnskip, btnClocation;

        String strAdd;
        TextView tvmap, textview;

        private boolean loggedIn = false;
        public static String email;


        private ProgressDialog myProgress;

        //Google ApiClient
        private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
        public int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            tvmap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_map);
            textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_euser);

            //progress bar
            myProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            myProgress.setTitle("Map Loading ...");
            myProgress.setMessage("Please wait...");
            myProgress.setCancelable(true);
            // Display Progress Bar.
            myProgress.show();

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            //Initializing googleapi client
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            //googleapi gps


            //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
            btnProceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_proceed);
            btnskip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
            //    btnClocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_clocation);

            btnProceed.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnskip.setOnClickListener(this);
            //    btnClocation.setOnClickListener(this);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
            email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");
            textview.setText(email);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (!enabled) {
                showDialogGPS();
            }

            super.onResume();
        }

        private void showDialogGPS() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Enable GPS");
            builder.setMessage("Please enable GPS");
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(
                            new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                   getCurrentLocation();
                    moveMap();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Ignore", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == btnProceed) {
                //    getCurrentLocation();
                //    moveMap();
                if (loggedIn) {
                    //We will start the Profile Activity

                    //    submitForm();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Maps_Activity1.this, Search_ActivityND.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            } else if (v == btnskip) {

                btnclick_skip();
            }

        }

        //dalete alert
        private void btnclick_skip() {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you fine this Location?");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            //   new JSONParserD().execute();
                            //Starting login activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Maps_Activity1.this, Search_ActivityND.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            //    if (loggedIn) {
                            //        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Home.class);
                            //        startActivity(intent);
                            //    }

                        }
                    });

            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });

            //Showing the alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }


        //saving to database
        private void submitForm() {

            caddress = tvmap.getText().toString();
            email = textview.getText().toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new MapAsync(this).execute(caddress, email);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            googleApiClient.connect();
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
            super.onStop();
        }

        //Getting current location
        private void getCurrentLocation() {
            mMap.clear();
            //Creating a location object

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.//

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                return;
            }

            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

            if (location != null) {
                //Getting longitude and latitude
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();

                //    tvmap.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

              //  strAdd = getCompleteAddressString1(latitude, longitude);
              //  tvmap.setText("Current Address : " + strAdd);
                getCompleteAddressString1(latitude,longitude);

                //moving the map to location
                moveMap();
            }

        }

        //Function to move the map
        private void moveMap() {
            //String to display current latitude and longitude
            String msg = latitude + ", " + longitude;

            //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            //Adding marker to map
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng) //setting position
                    .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                    .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

            //Moving the camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            //Animating the camera
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            mMap = googleMap;
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
            mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            getCurrentLocation();
            myProgress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            //Clearing all the markers
            mMap.clear();

            //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .draggable(true));
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            //Getting the coordinates
            latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            //Moving the map
            moveMap();
        }

        private String getCompleteAddressString1(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {

            strAdd = "";
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

                if (addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Current Address: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                    tvmap.setText(strAdd);
                } else {
                    tvmap.setText("No Address returned!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                tvmap.setText("Cannot get Address!");
            }
            return strAdd;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // permission was granted, yay! Do the

                        // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    //    getCurrentLocation();
                    //    moveMap();
                    } else {
                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                        Toast.makeText(Maps_Activity1.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return;
                }
                // other 'case' lines to check for other
                // permissions this app might request
            }
        }

        //Backpress button
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

Comment: Also give permission for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Comment: yes i already declare ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest

Comment: @rohiH Give that permission at `Run Time` too as you given for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

Comment: how i give this permission at run time?